# What Is The Difference Between A Recursive Dependency Check And A Reverse Dependency Check?

Tags: dependencies

My understanding of software dependencies is that a program package may require other packages to be installed, termed dependencies. A tree-like result ensues. Sometimes packages share common dependencies, but the package only needs to be installed once.

```
                                        |Package D
                  | Package B --------->|
                  |                     |Package E
Package A ------->|
                  |                     |Package F
                  | Package C --------->|
                                        |Package B
```

I recently [posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492435/how-to-download-apt-and-all-its-dependencies) a question on AskUbuntu.com about finding the dependencies of a package, and all the ways of doing this gave me different results. The reason for this was that some of the methods were apparently listing more than just dependencies, some were performing recursive checks, and some were performing reverse checks.

**What is the difference between a reverse dependency check, and a recursive dependency check?**

**EDIT:**

Citations for terms. I first heard them in the comments of a thread I posted about APT, but they are used in several programs that can be used to do dependency checks as well as on their manpages.

> apt-cache rdepends is looking for Reverse dependencies, my script and apt-rdepends are recursively looking for dependencies.

- Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492435/how-to-download-apt-and-all-its-dependencies

```
rdepends pkg(s)
           rdepends shows a listing of each reverse dependency a package has.
```

- Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/apt-cache.8.html

```
apt-rdepends - performs recursive dependency listings similar to
       apt-cache
```

- Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/apt-rdepends.8.html

Comment: Can you cite where those 2 terms were being used?

Comment: @slm I've given a few.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Reverse depends

Reverse depends means you want a list of packages that depend on a given package.

#### Example

```
$ apt-cache rdepends jetty
jetty
Reverse Depends:
  solr-jetty
  libjetty-java
  libjetty-extra-java
  libjetty-extra
  libini4j-java
  guacamole
```

#### Recursive depends

Using a tool such as `apt-rdepends` shows what packages a given package is dependent on, plus what packages these packages are also dependent on. This is performed recursively until the entire dependency tree is exhausted.

#### Example

```
$ apt-rdepends jetty | head -10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jetty
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: apache2-utils
  Depends: default-jre-headless
  Depends: java5-runtime-headless
  Depends: jsvc
  Depends: libjetty-java (>= 6.1.26-1ubuntu1)
adduser
  Depends: debconf
  Depends: debconf-2.0
...
```

Above you can see that `jetty` is dependent on `adduser` which itself is dependent on `debconf`.

#### Reverse recursive depends

This one shows what packages depend on a package that depends on a given package. This is again done recursively.

#### Example

```
$ apt-rdepends --reverse jetty 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jetty
  Reverse Depends: solr-jetty (>= 3.6.1+dfsg-0ubuntu2)
solr-jetty
  Reverse Depends: chef-solr (>= 10.12.0+dfsg-1)
chef-solr
  Reverse Depends: chef-expander (>= 10.12.0-1)
  Reverse Depends: chef-server-api (>= 10.12.0-1)
chef-expander
chef-server-api
  Reverse Depends: chef-server-webui (>= 10.12.0+dfsg-1)
chef-server-webui
```

Again here as the tree is explored the first package that lists `jetty` as a dependency is `solr-jetty`, which in turn is listed as a dependency for `chef-solr`, etc.

#### Types of depends

It can get a little confusing but there are a variety of depends. Looking at the man page for `apt-rdepends`:

```
   -f, --follow=DEPENDS
        A comma-separated list of DEPENDS types to follow recursively. 
        By default, it only follows the Depends and PreDepends types.

        The possible values for DEPENDS are: Depends, PreDepends, Suggests,
        Recommends, Conflicts, Replaces, and Obsoletes.

        In --build-depends mode, the possible values are: Build-Depends, 
        Build-Depends-Indep, Build-Conflicts, Build-Conflicts-Indep.
```

Comment: once again awesomness in a tube

Comment: What does "predepends" mean? And how is it different from "reverse depends"?

Comment: please ask that as a separate question, I would be interested to know about it as well.