# depends and build-depends in Debian

Tags: debian, dependencies

This comes partially from [What Is The Difference Between A Recursive Dependency Check And A Reverse Dependency Check?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141247/what-is-the-difference-between-a-recursive-dependency-check-and-a-reverse-depend/141276#141276)

I am still a bit confused so maybe somebody can make it clearer.

AFAIK, any package in Debian could be used in one of two ways:

- Runtime dependency - Runtime dependency means you cannot run a
  particular software as long as its runtime dependencies are not satisfied.
- Build-time dependencies, I guess this might be the same as the above
  runtime dependencies or something different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build-time would be what is needed to build the software, either in libraries (building a GTK "hello world"? you need libgtk-dev or whatever for the includes and then the libgtk libs as run-time dependencies too) OR in utilities ie you need some specific parser/generator/utility installed that is called during the configure/build process, like the `ncurses` -dev packages when you want to use `make menuconfig` to configure a Linux kernel.

I would bet that after you install the `build-essential` package that MOST of your build-time dependencies would be in the form of various source files, mostly headers/includes to use various libraries in addition to the standard C(++) library stuff.